# How to validate checkboxlist before hide through checkbox hide/show click function

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Form has checkbox which hide/display panel.

```
$(function () {
    $('[id$=Panel1]').hide();
    $('[id$=CheckBoxcard]').change(function () {
        if ($('[id$=CheckBoxcard]')[0].checked) {
            $('[id$=Panel1]').show();
        } else {
            $('[id$=Panel1]').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Panel has checkboxList and dropsownlist.dropdownlist is chained with checkboxlist.

```
$(function () {
    $('[id$=DropDownListsubcat]').hide();
    $('[id$=CheckBoxListcardiac] input:checkbox:first').click(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('[id$=DropDownListsubcat]').show();
        } else {
            $('[id$=DropDownListsubcat]').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

I would like to stop user to uncheck checkbox(which hide/display panel) if dropdownlist or checkboxlist have vales selected.

for example,user check checkbox and select values from checkboxlist and dropdownlist and user change his/her mind and just uncheck checkbox and hide panel.

How to stop user by doing that?

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I am new to asp,jquery and jsfiddle.net as well. I tried to write code but I don't see any result. here is link http://jsfiddle.net/cUA7S/1/

Thanks

Comment: @Matt, I'm pretty sure asp calls won't work on jsfiddle, however I'm interested in the answer to this question as well, so I'll be monitoring it.  I have no other useful input at this time.  Palash, if you know how to use asp on jsfiddle, please post an example, that would be incredibly useful to me.